# Releasing Gov't agreements related to Plant Hardiness Zone Map data

Tags: discussion

I made a FOIA request related to this question: [USDA Plant Hardiness Zone Map (PHZM) database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1884/1511). The research was government sponsored but the data is being sold to non-goverment people.

My request was denied, but a second request for the contracts between the government and the data-seller was granted. So now I have these contracts and I don't know what to do.

**My question:** Should I post them as an answer to the question? How else can I use them? **My goal** is to have the data in the public domain (and not just the maps).

[image: PHZM for reference]

Comment: sure, why not? release everything

Comment: This inspired me this non-meta question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/where-to-upload-open-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up sharing the contracts that I recieved by the FOIA.

The zipped folder and description are [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3233/1511).